# Enterprise Architect Date format for storing DateTime type tagged value

Tags: c#, datetime, enterprise-architect

In which format Enterprise Architect stores the values for `DateTime` type tagged values,in some cases it stores in `d/M/yyyy` or `M/d/yyyy` format.
Does it depend on the machine where EA is installed or the Machine where the Repository(Database) exist.

Comment: Are you sure they're stored as strings at all? I'd expect them to have some internal binary representation, and only get converted to strings for display...

Comment: Yeah, I am sure EA stores date as readable plain string,and returns string when we retrieve using Element.TaggedValues collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [forum post](http://www.sparxsystems.com/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?num=1411463245/0#0) there might be a bug in EA v11 that makes it store date in a different format as opposed to v10.

Answer (score 2):

As answered by Geert and it is confirmed by EA support that date format differs for both the formats of EA 10 and 11,
and in addition 
For EA 10, if a date type tagged value is added to a element with default value then it is stored and retrieved in a different format and once it is changed to some other date after that date value for that element is stored in consistent format.

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't know anything about Enterprise Architect but I would guess..

> In which format Enterprise Architect stores the values for DateTime
>   type tagged values,in some cases it stores in d/M/yyyy or M/d/yyyy
>   format.

A [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) doesn't have *any* implicit format. It just has date and time values. Textual representatsion of a `DateTime` (also called `string` representation) can have a format. I don't believe they are stored `DateTime` values as a `string`. They probably only use some formats when they want to display them.

> Does it depend on the machine where EA is installed or the Machine
>   where the Repository(Database) exist

This depends on which culture they use their `DateTime`'s representation. If they don't use any [`IFormatProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in their methods, it uses [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the machine where the codes are executed. If they use [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for example, this doesn't depends on which culture they have since it is culture-independent.